# RVest scraping of data and image title

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to scrape both data and the title of an image.

```
library(rvest) 

    test <- paste0("https://247sports.com/Season/2021-Football/Commits/?Page=", 1:38)
    
    test_data <- map_df(commits, ~.x %>% read_html %>%
                         html_nodes(".ri-page__star-and-score .score , .position , .ri-page__name-link") %>%
                         html_text() %>% 
                         str_trim %>% 
                         str_split("   ") %>% 
                         matrix(ncol = 3, byrow = T) %>% 
                         as.data.frame)
```

That gives me the four fields of data I need. But I also want to get the image title, which lives in:

```
<img alt="South Carolina" class="jsonly" src="https://s3media.247sports.com/Uploads/Assets/627/649/4649627.png?fit=bounds&amp;crop=50:50,offset-y0.50&amp;width=50&amp;height=50" title="South Carolina" style="opacity: 1;">
```

So I want to also extract either alt or title, both of which give me the name (in this example, it's `South Carolina`). I know how to extract this as only the title using `httr_attr` but I don't know how to combine them all together so it's five total fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the title by :

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

test <- 'https://247sports.com/Season/2021-Football/Commits/?Page=1'

test_data$title <- test %>%
                    read_html %>%
                    html_nodes('div.status img') %>%
                    html_attr('title') %>%
                   .[c(TRUE, FALSE)]

test_data
#                    V1                  V2     V3   V4              title
#1           Kyle Ecker Committed: 8/5/2020     NA   OT          San Diego
#2     Josh Bertholotte Committed: 8/5/2020     NA  OLB             Hawaii
#3        Antario Brown Committed: 8/5/2020 0.8516   RB     South Carolina
#4       J'Kalon Carter Committed: 8/5/2020     NA   WR     Illinois State
#5       Stephon Dubose Committed: 8/5/2020     NA   OG       Old Dominion
#...
```

I use `.[c(TRUE, FALSE)]` to select alternate values because using `html_attr('title')` returns every value twice.

---

To integrate it in the `map` function we can do :

```
all_data <- map_df(commits, ~{
             webpage <- .x %>% read_html
             df1 <-  webpage %>%
                    html_nodes(".ri-page__star-and-score .score ,.position ,.ri-page__name-link") %>%
                    html_text() %>% 
                    str_trim %>% 
                    str_split("   ") %>% 
                    matrix(ncol = 3, byrow = T) %>% 
                    as.data.frame
             df1$title <- webpage %>%
                            html_nodes('div.status img') %>%
                            html_attr('title') %>%
                           .[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
             df1
})
```

Comment: Thank you, but does this require me to run both my script from above and yours seperate? This is ultimately part of a `map_df` function, so I'd like to have it in one run.

Comment: Yes, you need to do it separately because the other 4 values are in text and this is value is in one of the attribute. You can edit your post to include `map_df` code if you have trouble integrating this into it.

Comment: Can you check the updated answer and see if it helps?

Comment: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "title", value = c("California", "Syracuse",  : 
  replacement has 49 rows, data has 50

Comment: Which page returns that error? Can you go to that page and see if all `Status` value is present?

Comment: How would I know which page?

Comment: Ok..some of them do not have the anchor tag. I removed it from `html_nodes`. Try updated answer.

Comment: Jackpot! Thank you. I really appreciate your help and patience.